# Conditional Probability that I am confused on

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question based on Conditional Probability: A teacher is about to go up for review. Two judges selected at random from a committee of three evaluators: B, C, and E with probabilities of .4, .6, and .7 of giving teacher A a high score.

What is the probability that both judges give her a high score?
I am confused on this.

Given that she got two scores, what is the probability that her evaluators were prof C and E?

So this is the $P(C \cap E|2 high scores)$. right? If I am correct then by Bayers formula we have $P(CE2highscores)/P(2highscores)$

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the first part of the question:**

The probability of choosing each pair of judges is:

$$\frac{1}{\binom32}=\frac13$$

The probability of judges B and C giving a high score is:

$$0.4\cdot0.6=0.24$$

The probability of judges B and E giving a high score is:

$$0.4\cdot0.7=0.28$$

The probability of judges C and E giving a high score is:

$$0.6\cdot0.7=0.42$$

So the probability of both judges giving a high score is:

$$\frac13\cdot0.24+\frac13\cdot0.28+\frac13\cdot0.42=\frac{47}{150}\approx31.3\%$$

---

**Answering the second part of the question:**

The probability that the high score was given by judges C and E is:

$$\frac{\frac13\cdot0.42}{\frac13\cdot0.24+\frac13\cdot0.28+\frac13\cdot0.42}=\frac{21}{47}\approx44.68\%$$